# ACCOSA PG payment gateway integration in magento

Tags: php, magento, payment-gateway

I am developing one client site using magento version 1.9. Now the client wants to integrate their payment gateway. They are purchasing ACCOSA PG payment gateway(before i never heard of that). I have to integrate ACCOSA PG payment gateway with my magento project.

Is that possible in magento. If yes Please let me know how to do it .Is there any example or code i can go through?.

Thanks,
Ravichandran